# Configuring apache2.conf webobjects.conf in Debian

Tags: apache, debian, webobjects

This is a very simple question, but I have struggled for two days to start up my WebObjects on a deployment Debian server. Everything has worked fine so far with Eclipse and Direct Connect, and an apachectl -M shows that the webobjects module (http server) is installed, running and shared. But when I try to run something as simple as a Hello World the browser returns a 404.

My applications are in /usr/share/webobjects/Library/WebObjects/JavaApplications/

Any pointers as to how I should configure (symbolic links and .conf entries) to make this work?

Much appreciated.

Luis

Comment: A little progress: I have changes permissions and now I can see the .woa directories from the browser, but when I go to a specific port, as in http:host/cgi-bin/WebObjects/HelloWorld.woa/-35987 I get a 403: "You don't have permission to access /cgi-bin/WebObjects/HelloWorld.woa/-53037 on this server.

Comment: More progress! I edited the apache2.conf to read:

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>

And know it seems to recognize the request but not the application:

"The requested application was not found on this server."

So I guess it's only a matter of directories now...

Comment: It's not working. The funny thing is that JavaMonitor DOES work both in DirectConnect Mode and with the HTTP adaptor. I tried a version of Hello World without Project Wonder (i.e. just WO classes) to see if the problem was PW, but it has the same beheviour. I am at my wit's end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at the [Deploying on Linux](https://wiki.wocommunity.org/display/documentation/Deploying+on+Linux) page on the WOCommunity wiki? If that doesn't help, you may need to post the relevant sections of your `httpd.conf` here for inspection.